# Banner only works on certain accounts

Tags: python, kivy

I added an ad banner in my app using Kivmob and it perfectly works with the test banner. But when I try with my admob account, the banner is not showing. My account has been verified so this should work. Here is the piece of code where my ad is integrated:

```
class GuessApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.ads = KivMob("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", top_pos=False)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    """Class for the main screen widget"""
    pass
```

I also made the appropriate modifications in the buildozer.spec file.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = hostpython3, kivy, android, jnius, kivmob

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 24

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19b

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Using adb logcat I got this error:

```
05-24 11:26:59.033 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] __init__ called.
05-24 11:26:59.033 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] Android platform detected.
05-24 11:26:59.034 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] new_banner() called.
05-24 11:26:59.034 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] request_banner() called.
05-24 11:26:59.035 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivMob      ] show_banner() called.
05-24 11:26:59.065 17896 17929 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
05-24 11:26:59.077 17896 17929 E libEGL  : validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

What is wrong ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

## Hello! I am with the same problem

## When I put that Test code below the banner works on my app

def build(self):

```
self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
self.ads.new_banner(TestIds.BANNER, top_pos=True)
self.ads.request_banner()
self.ads.show_banner()
```

## but when I change to my id from Admob I can't see the banner

def build(self):

```
self.ads = KivMob("ca-app-pub-6537268165660~4490902")
self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-6537265528660/4450902", top_pos=True)
self.ads.request_banner()
self.ads.show_banner()
```

Comment: Finally, I don't think there is a bug. In my Admob account, I can clearly see ads requests from my app. So my guess is that you need a sufficient number of requests from a certain number of devices to start showing ads.
Be careful, there is an ID for your app and an ID for each of your ad widgets (here your banner). You should not have the same ID in your 1st and 2nd line.

Comment: Does your app is working now with ad banner? How can you fix it using kivmob? Another question why I have 2 IDs and which of them I need to use? Thank you very much my friend. Do you have Instagram or Telegram? I was looking for kivmob but it's hard to find something or someone to help....

Comment: No, my app is not public yet but it will be soon and I'll let you know about the banner. If you go into your Admob account you will find your app ID in Application settings menu and your banner ID in the Ad units menu. Use the app ID when calling the KivMob() class and the banner ID when calling the new_banner method.
I know, it's hard to find information about kivmob ...